# Get return from function and then use in promise.all()?

Tags: javascript, json, sqlite, promise

I have three functions each of which performs a SQL query and returns me an array of data; I know this part is working because I can do a json.stringify before returning the array and it works as intended. The problem is that I need to wait until these three functions finish and then do some more stuff with them.

Each function I use has this same call structure:

```
this.foo.makeFullJSON().then((fooStorage) => {
    fooJSON = '{foo:[' + JSON.stringify(fooStorage) + ']}';
});
```

I'm aware I should have an array of promises and then push the promises to it and then use Promise.all(), but I don't really know what part of the code I'd actually have to do that on.

Edit: Clearing up, each makeFullJSON() I call returns a promise ( of an array ). I need to do stuff with that resulting array.

Comment: Did you read [any documentation for `Promise.all()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all)?  What specific part did you not understand?

Comment: I had read, but it somehow escaped me that Promise.all() returned an array of the resolved promises.

I guess you've solved the question.

Comment: `Promise.all()` returns a new master promise.  Calling `.then()` on that master promise gets your callback access to an array of fulfilled values (not promises) from all the promises that you passed to `Promise.all()`.  So, in your `.then()` handler, you get an array of fulfilled values.

Comment: I thought that should have been illustrated well in the answer I gave. All the resolved values are passed to the `.then` from the `promise.all`

Comment: That's correct, but I had thought the answer wrong because I got confused with having to create promises and then push them in an array of promises; I didn't realize it could've just been Promise.all([p1,p2,p3]) in your answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assign the promise to a variable when you create it, and then you can pass that variable into [promise.all()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all).

Since I cannot see the full implementation of your code, here is a working, slimmed down version of how this works with promises, mocked with some similar names.

```js
function makeFullJSON(time) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(resolve, time, [time]); // send back an array for simulation
  })
}

var p1 = makeFullJSON(1000);
var p2 = makeFullJSON(500);
var p3 = makeFullJSON(750);

p1.then(array => {
  console.log('Promise 1 complete', array);
  // Do other stuff with the return value
});

p2.then(array => {
  console.log('Promise 2 complete', array);
});

p3.then(array => {
  console.log('Promise 3 complete', array);
});

Promise
  .all([p1, p2, p3])
  .then(arrayOfAllResolvedValues => {
    // This array will contain values; the values from the
    // resolved promises in order of adding them to the promises array
    console.log('Array of resolved values:', arrayOfAllResolvedValues);
  });
```

Comment: Not sure, but it seems as if `makeFullJSON` already returns a `Promise`, because the OP applies `then` to it.

Comment: Right. Since I can't see their code, I am mocking the same scenario where `makeFullJSON ` returns a promise. In my case, yes, my promise has nothing to do with JSON, it just simulates how OP's code is working, and how they can resolve after all promises have.

Comment: Edited OP for clarity; I understand I can use something akin to:

    var promises = [];

And then with each function that returns a promise I can do:

    promises.push(function())

And then have:

    Promise.all(promises).then(() => {stuff});

To wait until they're all done, but that's not the problem; the problem is that I need to do things with the individual returns of each function I call.

Comment: @Arfons, I'm not sure I added any more clarity. But you can already do stuff with the return value to each promise. You do it where you call `.then` for that particular promise. But, you can also pass all resolved variables from the `promise.all()` into the .then chain. I've made some updates to my answer. Let me know if they help or not

Answer (score 0):

`Promise.all()` needs an array of promises as it's parameter.
You can simply call

```
Promise.all([
    this.foo.makeFullJSON1(),
    this.foo.makeFullJSON2(),
    ...]);
```

Since calling these functions will return promise objects.